# How do I let my Tkinter-Canvas have a fixed width/height ratio when resizing the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have the following chessboard:
[image: Chessboard]

And I want the canvas which holds the chessboard to always remain a square, no matter how I resize the Window, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This can get complicated if you have multiple items in a window and want to constrain a single widget. The correct answer will depend on what else is going on in the window and what sort of resize behavior you've defined.

A simple method is to make sure that the canvas is in a region that will not resize. For example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="bisque")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

You can also constrain the window as a whole to a specific aspect ratio with `wm_aspect`. This lets you resize the window, but the window as a whole will retain a specific aspect ratio.

For example, to force the root window to be a square you can do this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_aspect(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

From the tcl/tk man pages (and translated to python syntax):

> *window*.wm_aspect(?minNumer minDenom maxNumer maxDenom?) - If *minNumer*, *minDenom*, *maxNumer*, and *maxDenom* are all specified, then they will be passed to the window manager and the window manager should use them to enforce a range of acceptable aspect ratios for window. The aspect ratio of window (width/length) will be constrained to lie between *minNumer/minDenom* and *maxNumer/maxDenom*. If *minNumer* etc. are all specified as empty strings, then any existing aspect ratio restrictions are removed. If *minNumer* etc. are specified, then the command returns an empty string. Otherwise, it returns a tuple containing four elements, which are the current values of *minNumer*, *minDenom*, *maxNumer*, and *maxDenom* (if no aspect restrictions are in effect, then an empty string is returned).

Comment: `wm_aspect` is not supported by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to your problem. Here is one with `grid` manager and `Canvas` of fixed size. If you want to resize the `Canvas`, you must use a bind to `<Configure>` event to keep its size square:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

b = ttk.Button(text='test')
b.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg="bisque")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky='nw')

root.mainloop()
```